# useState, useMemo keeps reseting value on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was trying to get the total value of marks on a table of student exam scores. On save changes I get the correct value. But on browser refresh the value to 0. I used `useEffect()` and `useMemo()` hooks but kept getting the same result. But I used normal variable, (not `useState()` hook), the values stays even after refresh.

Here is the code.

```
 const englishSubmitted = JSON.parse(
    localStorage.getItem("englishSubmitted") as string
  );
 const [englishResult, setEnglishResult] = useState<
    { [key: string]: string }[]
  >([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (englishSubmitted) {
      setEnglishResult(
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("englishAnswers") as string)
      );
    }
},[])


`// this does not work`
  useEffect(() => {
    const value = englishResult.reduce((acc, current) => {
      acc += parseInt(current.marks);
      return acc;
    }, 0);
    setEnglishMarks(value);
  }, []);

`//this does not work either`
  useMemo(() => {
    const value = englishResult.reduce((acc, current) => {
      acc += parseInt(current.marks);
      return acc;
    }, 0);
    setEnglishMarks(value);
  }, []);
```

Putting a value in the dependency array does not work either.

But the following code works. the `value` variable retains its value even after refresh

```
    const value = englishResult.reduce((acc, current) => {
      acc += parseInt(current.marks);
      return acc;
    }, 0);
```

Comment: If you refresh a browser nothing gets stored unless you tell it somehow.  Eg, localStorage, hash params, history state, indexDb etc.

Comment: Are you persisting this data anywhere?  Otherwise I certainly wouldn't expect it to be retained on a page reload.  I suspect your test about what "works" vs. "doesn't work" may be mistaken and/or based on false assumptions.

Comment: `englishResult` is an array of objects stored in localStorage from another component route. I am just getting the values to display here. That's why it's expected to be available on page refresh.

Comment: @MisbahuAbubakar: In that case it sounds like the code shown isn't a [mcve].  Can you provide a more complete test that we can execute and observe, and indicate specifically what isn't working as expected in that test?

Answer (score 2):

> But the following code works. the value variable retains its value even after refresh
>
> ```
> const value = englishResult.reduce((acc, current) => {
>   acc += parseInt(current.marks);
>   return acc;
> }, 0);
> ```

That's the code i would recommend anyway for a computed value like this one. Copying it into a different state just makes the component do extra renders and complicates the code.

If the array is particularly large, such that it's causing you a performance issue, you can skip the calculation if nothing has changed by doing useMemo like this:

```
const value = useMemo(() => {
  return englishResult.reduce((acc, current) => {
    acc += parseInt(current.marks);
    return acc;
  }, 0);
}, [englishResult])
```

Note that you should not set state in useMemo. Just return the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use localStorage for that:
For example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-react-hooks